# Finding the smallest sub-family of subsets needed to form a new subset

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, packing-problem

**TL/DR**

I have a universe $U$ of items $u_i$ and a family $F$ of subsets of $U$ (call them $P_j$ ⊆ $U$).

Given this family of subsets, I would like to find the sub-family $C$ ⊆ $F$ of subsets that can produce a new subset $P_{new}$ of members $u_i$ by adding together (or subtracting) as few subsets $P_j$ as possible.

That's the best I can do. Hopefully an example is more clear:

---

**Example**

For instance, if we start with the following family of subsets:

$$ \begin{align}
 F = \{&P_1 = \{a\},\ P_2 = \{b\},\ ...,\ P_{16} = \{p\}, \\
   &P_{17} = \{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p\}, \\ 
   &P_{18} = \{a, b, c, d, e\}, \\
   &P_{19} = \{g, h, i\} \,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \}&\\
\end{align} $$

When requested to compute $\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i\}$, the simplest thing to do is calculate:

$$\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i\} =  \{a\} + \{b\} + \{c\} +\ ...\ + \{h\} + \{i\}$$

This isn't optimal though (requires 8 additions). For instance, I know that I could more quickly produce the set if I instead took advantage of my previously computed sets (using 2 additions):

$$ \begin{align}
P_{new} &= \{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i\}\\
  &=  \{a, b, c, d, e\} + \{f\} + \{g, h, i\} \\
  &=  P_{18} + P_{6} + P_{19} \\
 \mathord{\therefore}\ C ⊆ F &= \{ P_{6}, P_{18}, P_{19} \} \\
\end{align} $$

---

**Example 2**

What's even more complex is that (if possible) I want to know when involving subtraction might be optimal:

$$\{e, f, g, h, i\} = \{e\} + \{f\} + \{g, h, i\}$$

This is the best solution using only addition (2 operations), But I could have gotten this even faster with 1 subtraction:

$$\{e, f, g, h, i\} = \{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i\} - \{a, b, c, d\}$$

---

**Why I need this**

Each subset $P_j$ has a value $p_j = f(P_j)$ that can be computed. The function $f(P_j)$ is additive. So $p_{\{1,2\}} = p_{\{1\}} + p_{\{2\}}$

When I start my application, I start only by calculating the value $p_i$ for each item $l_i$ on its own. For example:

$$ \begin{align}
   P_1 = \{a\} ,&\ \ p_1 = f(P_1) = 5 \\
   P_2 = \{b\} ,&\ \ p_2 = f(P_2) = 20 \\
   P_3 = \{c\} ,&\ \ p_3 = f(P_3) = 8 \\
   ...\ &
\end{align} $$

I then have to start servicing requests for different subsets. For example:

$$ \begin{align}
    P_{18} &=  \{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p\}\  &f(P_{18}) &= 400 \\
    P_{19} &=  \{b, c, d\}\                                         &f(P_{19}) &= 43\\
    P_{20} &=  \{g, h, i\}\                                         &f(P_{20}) &= 30 \\
    ...&
\end{align} $$

My goal is to be able to process these request as fast as possible. For early requests, I unavoidably have to spend a lot of time adding up $p_j$ values. But since these values are additive, I know there should be faster ways to process requests by taking advantage of sets for which I've already computed $p_j$.

If $P_{21} = \{b, c, d, g, h, i\}$ is requested, I don't want to waste precious resources retrieving the the 6 values for $p_{2}$ to $p_{7}$, and then adding these values in 5 lengthy operations, when I could have just done a single operation $p_{21} = p_{19}+p_{20}$.

---

**Not set-theory?**

This might actually be a better fit for linear algebra, if formulated as follows:

If I have the following known equations and values:

$$ \begin{align}
    P_{1}  &=  a, P_{2}  =  b,\ ...,\ P_{8}  =  g &f(P_{1})  &= p_{1},\ ...\\
    P_{9}  &=  a + b + c + d   &f(P_{9})  &= p_{9} \\
    P_{10} &=  d + e + f + g   &f(P_{10}) &= p_{10} \\
\end{align} $$

And I wish to calculate

$$ \begin{align}
    P_{11} &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g  &f(P_{11}) ? \\
\end{align} $$

I want to be able discover that the fastest solution comes from

$$ \begin{align}
    P_{11} &= P_{9} + P_{10} - P_{4} \\
    P_{11} &=  (a + b + c + d) + (d + e + f + g) - (d) \\
           &=  (a + b + c + 2d + e + f + g) - (d) \\
           &=  a + b + c + d + e + f + g\ \checkmark\\
           \mathord{\therefore}\ p_{11} &= p_{9} + p_{10} - p_{4} \\
\end{align} $$

It's starting to look suspiciously like an np hard problem to me :( If no one can come up with an elegant way of solving the problem, I would also accept a more elegant way of wording the problem (perhaps in terms of an existing well known problem), or a bound on the complexity.

Comment: If anyone has any question about whether it's worthwhile - the problem I'm applying this to is one where we have maybe hundreds of cached subsets to work with. Each time I add two sets together, I have to perform ~1 million operations. That means to form a new set of 11 items currently takes ~10 million ops. As the number of already computed sets increases, sure it will take more time to find the optimal family of sets to add together, but I expect to net far less ops in total.

Comment: Just to be sure: you don't want repetition of elements in the unions, correct? And if I was to add some element twice, and then remove it once, would said element be counted as present exactly once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, first let's work on a formal representation of your problem.

- Let $m$ be the number of computed sets.
- Let $n$ be the number of elements in the universe
- Let $U=\{u_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be the universe
- Let $S$ be the set of all subsets of $U$
- Let $\{P_j\}_{j=1}^{m}$ be the already computed sets
- Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix
- Let $A_{ij} = \cases{\begin{array}[c]\\1,\,u_i \in P_j \\0,\,u_i \notin P_j \end{array}}$
- Let $c(x) = \cases{\begin{array}[c]\\0,\,x=0\\1,\, x \ne 0 \\ \end{array}}$
- Let $v(s): S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function that creates a vector representation of a subset of $U$. Define $v(s) = \left[\begin{array}[c]\\v(s)_1\\v(s)_2\\ \,\,\,\,\vdots \\ v(s)_n \end{array}\right]$ and $v(s)_i = \cases{\begin{array}[c]\\1, \, u_i \in s\\0, \, u_i \notin s \end{array} }$
- Let $f$ be the function as defined in the original question.

The first thing to note is that since $f$ is linear, and we have a new input set $P^*$, if we can find a vector $q \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $Aq = v(P^*)$, then $f(P^*) = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i \cdot f(P_i)$.  Furthermore, note that the cost of computing $f(P^*)$ using the formula above is $C(q) = \sum_{i=1}^m c(q_i) $.

With all of that, we have our optimization problem:
$$ 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\begin{align} \\
q^*(P^*)&=\argmin_q C(q) \text{ such that }Aq=v(P^*)
\end{align}
$$

$C$ is piecewise constant function, meaning it has discontinuities both in value and in derivative. Furthermore, if any of the existing subsets are not used in the optimal calculation, it will have a discontinuous derivative at the optimal point. The input vector $q$ can take on any value in $\mathbb{R}^m$. The constraint is a linear equality constraint.

So at first blush, this is a nonsmooth optimization problem with linear equality constraints.

---

There's also another way to think about the objective function. Suppose we have a guess about which variables are non-zero in the optimal solution. Represent this by a vector with $m$ elements, each either one or zero, which we will call $b$. Can we determine whether this set of subsets to use in the calculation is feasible, and if so, what the appropriate weights are? We can. Simply remove the columns of $A$ and the entries in $q$ corresponding to the $0$ entries in $b$, and solve the resulting problem in a least squares sense. If the solution is feasible, it will have a zero residual. Otherwise, it will have non-zero residuals. If we use $b$ as our input variable instead of $q$ we end up with a nicer objective function, with more restriction on available inputs (each entry of b can be either 1 or 0):

$$
\begin{align} \\
D(b) &= 1^Tb
\end{align}
$$

Now we just need to specify a set of constraints that make that objective function work. First, we specify the least squares problem we need to solve inside the constraint function:
$$
\begin{align} \\
\bar{A}\bar{q} &= v(P^*)
\end{align}
$$

The least squares solution is :
$$ 
\begin{align} \\
\hat{q} &= \argmin_{\bar{q}} (\bar{A}\bar{q} - v(P^*))^T (\bar{A}\bar{q} - v(P^*)) \\
\hat{q} &= \left(\bar{A}^T \bar{A} \right)^{-1} \bar{A}^T v(P^*) \\
\end{align}
$$

And our constraint is $ (\bar{A}\hat{q} - v(P^*))^T(\bar{A}\hat{q} - v(P^*)) = 0 $. In this, it's important to note that $\bar{A}$ and $\hat{q}$ are functions of the input variable $b$.

So, under this formulation of the problem, we have a linear binary programming problem with a nonlinear equality constraint.

---

Both of these types of problems are NP complete. There are, however, algorithms that can help solve these types of problems, or at least get somewhat close to an optimal solution, in a reasonable amount of computation time. For the first problem formulation, you can look at genetic/evolutionary global optimizers, or direct/pattern search algorithms. These are somewhat common, and included, for instance, in MATLAB's optimization toolbox. The second section approach is a pretty exotic problem, and probably shouldn't be the focus of your search for an optimizer, although I think there are some academic papers that might help solve that formulation.

Comment: I was able to follow you through the formal definition of the optimization problem, but not surprisingly, much of the discussion surrounding the formulation of a solution (especially the constraint syntax) is over my head. I can research that in time though. My impression is that you've correctly understood my problem, so I'm inclined to accept this immediately to thank you for your effort, and hope you'll be awarded the bounty as well.

Comment: I added some horizontal rules to divide the answer into sections. If you understand sections 1 and 3, you probably understand everything you need to know. When I started section 2, I thought that approach was going to make the problem tractable, but it turned out not to. Because of that, there's not much advantage to the section 2 approach. If you have specific questions, I can probably clear them up.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but I'm not allowed to comment, and I have a question, so here goes:

In parts of your problem you make it sound like the point of your program is to calculate $f(P)$ for a user input $P \subseteq U$. You also say that $f$ is linear, and that you calculate $f$ for every single element set in startup. Suppose that the number of elements in the universe is $u$ and the number of elements in the requested subset is $r$. Then the lookup time for the function value of each element in the request is $\approx O(1)$ if you use a hash table, or $O(\log_2u)$ using a binary search tree. Thus the total time for requesting function values is $O(r\log_2u)$ or $O(r)$. The addition time would be $O(r)$. So overall you're looking at a runtime of $O(r)$ or $O(r\log_2u)$. Which seems fine. The only way you have a problem here that doesn't make the problem completely unsolvable is if it's not the function call that's expensive, but the addition operation. If that's the case, then we need more information about the cost properties of the addition operation to answer the question.

For instance, assuming $f(P1)$ is computed, is computing $nf(P1)$ more expensive than simply fetching $f(P1)$? Is that computation linear in $n$? Quadratic? How about the computation costs of $f(P1)-f(P2)$ vs $f(P1)+f(P3)$, where $P2$ and $P3$ have the same size. Bottom line, unless I completely misunderstand the question, we need more information to answer it.

Comment: Yes, the point of the program is to calculate $f(P)$. Fetching $f(P1)$ is, for all intensive purposes, instantaneous - so don't worry about that. What's expensive is adding or subtracting together any two $f(Pn)$ (they are very very large vectors), which is why I want to find, ahead of time, the minimum number of additions and subtractions I can make to produce $f(P)$. And yes, adding or subtracting any two $f(Pn)$ takes about the same amount of time as multiplying any $f(Pn)$ by a constant, since each element in the vector would have to be iterated over.

Comment: Essentially, iterating over a vector $Pn$ takes so incredibly long, I want to know how to calculate some new $f(P)$ in the smallest number of iterations possible. This generally becomes the problem "calculate some new $f(P)$ while touching as few of the vectors $Pn$" as possible - a smallest set problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reformulate the problem in terms of linear algebra. Let the universe $U$ be finite, and consider the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^U$ of vectors $\mathbf{x}=(x_u)_{u\in U}$. We associate to every subset $S\subseteq U$ a vector $\mathbf{x}_S\in V$ by
$$\mathbf{x}_u=\cases{1&if $u\in S$\\0&if $u\notin S$}$$
Then, given $F\subseteq\mathcal{P}(U)$, the problem of writing some subset $P\subseteq U$ as a sum (resp. sum and subtraction) of elements of $F$ is exactly the problem of finding a solution *containing only $0$'s and $1$'s* (resp. $0$'s, $1$'s and $-1$'s) of
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}_P$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the matrix with columns $\mathbf{x}_f$ for $f\in F$. Thus your problem reduces to finding some particular lattice points of a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^F$. Unfortunately I know very little on the subject, and I am unable to help you any further, but I am sure somebody else will. Good luck.

Addendum: Notice that once you have found all those lattice points you can find the ones corresponding to the minimal number of needed operations by minimizing $\|\mathbf{y}\|_1=\sum_{f\in F}|y_f|$.

Comment: I would like to know why my answer was downvoted...